# Backround cover в Chrome Mobile

Tags: css

Фоновое изображение назначается тегу `body` следующим образом:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-image: url(images/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: top center;
}
```

Всё бы ничего, но в Chrome Mobile после того, как скрывается строка адреса, снизу появляется белый отступ размером со строку адреса (на рис. 2 обведено красным).

Какие могут быть варианты решения?

[image: С адресной строкой]
[image: Без адресной строки]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось решить проблему, созданием дополнительного фиксированного `div` с отрицательным значением `z-index`. Соответственно, фон теперь назначается этому `div`, а не `body`:

```
.site-bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -999;
    background-image: url(images/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: top center;
}
```

Тот ещё костыль, но с задачей справляется. Если кто-то подскажет более элегантное решение, буду весьма признателен.

**UPD:**

Как выяснилось, такой вариант плохо работает в Chrome на iOS. Фон растягивается и дёргается при прокрутке страницы.
Для решения проблемы был найден альтернативный вариант - не давать браузеру скрывать адресную строку. Делается это так:

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;
}
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}
```

Увы, такой вариант подойдёт далеко не всем и не всегда. В этом случае можно скриптом назначать высоту элементу с фоном по событию `resize` окна.